# No visible @interface for UITableViewCell declares the selector didReceiveMemoryWarning

Tags: ios, tableview, uitableview, viewdidload

Can anyone let me know why I get this error

> No visible @interface for `UITableViewCell` declares the selector `didReceiveMemoryWarning`

When using the code below:

```
- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
  [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
  // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
```

Comment: Because is an instance method of `UIViewController` (and not a `UITableViewCell`)

Answer (score 4):

Because `didReceiveMemoryWarning()` is a method inheritable from the `UIViewController` class and it's not available in classes like `UITableViewCell` (which inherits from `UIView`).

Furthermore, `didReceiveMemoryWarning()` is called when the system detects that is running with low memory:

```
open func didReceiveMemoryWarning() 
// Called when the parent application receives a memory warning. 
// On iOS 6.0 it will no longer clear the view by default.
```

Answer (score 0):

Refer to the apple doc:https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621409-didreceivememorywarning

> Sent to the view controller when the app receives a memory warning.
>
> Your app never calls this method directly. Instead, this method is called when the system determines that the amount of available memory is low.

So, you should know this method invoked is caused by the low momery.